# "PInvokeStackImbalance Was Detected"

Tags: vb.net

I keep on getting "PInvokeStackImbalance was detected" with the following line:

```
Shift = GetAsyncKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.ShiftKey)
```

Any way I can solve this?

Comment: Show how exactly you are importing that function.

Comment: [According to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0htdy0k3.aspx): **Resolution** Review the managed platform invoke signature and calling convention to confirm it matches the signature and calling convention of the native target. Try explicitly specifying the calling convention on both the managed and unmanaged sides. It is also possible, although not as likely, that the unmanaged function unbalanced the stack for some other reason, such as a bug in the unmanaged compiler.